# Button Touching Error

Tags: android, andengine

I'm developing a game with Andengine.I used HUD for game controller buttons.But I got a bug in it.The bug is: When I pressed the button and move my finger outside of the buttun without isActionUp, the button being pressed always.How can I solve this?
I tried .isActionOutside() feature but it doesn't work!

this code for button that I use:

```
ButtonSprite left = new  ButtonSprite(75, 75, ResourcesManager.getInstance().leftButtonRegion, vbom) {
        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pTouchEvent, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
            if(pTouchEvent.isActionDown()) {
               this.setCurrentTileIndex(1);
               player.moveX(-3);
            }
            if(pTouchEvent.isActionOutside() || pTouchEvent.isActionUp()) {
                this.setCurrentTileIndex(0);
                player.stopMovingX();
             }
            return super.onAreaTouched(pTouchEvent, pTouchAreaLocalX, pTouchAreaLocalY);
        }
    };
    gameHUD.registerTouchArea(left);
    gameHUD.attachChild(left);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be getting at least one of either `ACTION_UP` or `ACTION_OUTSIDE`, depending on what the user does. I suggest you to debug all the `TouchEvent`s you get, i.e add a `Log` call line inside the `onTouchEvent` method, and see what events you get when the finger moves off the button.

Another option I can suggest is to check the local touch coordinates (`pTouchAreaLocalX`, `pTouchAreaLocalY`). Maybe you get one last `TouchEvent` when the finger moves off the button, so compare the coordinates to the size of the button (Since the button is 75x75, if either of the coordinates is < 0 or > 75, it's outside of the button.)

Comment: it's still not working. I think the problem is about HUD. Because when I use Sprite and its isActionDown, it is working, but when I attach this sprite to HUD, it is not working. Working but there is bug I said above!

Comment: Is your HUD set as a touch area itself?

Answer (score 0):

```
gameHUD = new HUD();

ButtonSprite left = new  ButtonSprite(75, 75, ResourcesManager.getInstance().leftButtonRegion, vbom) {
        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pTouchEvent, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
            if(pTouchEvent.isActionDown()) {
               this.setCurrentTileIndex(1);
               player.moveX(-3);
            }
            if(pTouchEvent.isActionOutside() || pTouchEvent.isActionUp()) {
                this.setCurrentTileIndex(0);
                player.stopMovingX();
             }
            return super.onAreaTouched(pTouchEvent, pTouchAreaLocalX, pTouchAreaLocalY);
        }
    };
gameHUD.registerTouchArea(left);
gameHUD.attachChild(left);

camera.setHUD(gameHUD);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gameHUD.setTouchAreaBindingOnActionDownEnabled(true);
```

this line worked.Thanks for your interestings..